# Recorded Robo Test fails to execute any actions

Tags: firebase-test-lab

I've recorded a simple login Robo Test to be executed by App Crawler.  I've provided the script to app crawler, and I see in the logs where it loads it, and tries to execute it.  However, it always fails at the first action by saying it cannot find the Element.

I see on the screen where it tries to start executing the actions, but it immediately says it executed zero actions and then goes into the pre-canned scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason for such cases is that your app looks/behaves differently during recording and replaying phases. In particular:

- Your app might be built with one app package id for debug APK (which is used for Roboscript recording) and a different one for release APK (which you use to perform a Robo crawl with the recorded Roboscript).
- Your app might show different dialogs or have a somewhat different screen setup during recording and replaying phases (e.g., due to different environments and/or versions).

You either need to ensure a consistent app look/behavior or modify the recorded Roboscript to remove attributes that are different during recording and replaying phases (e.g., resource ids that use app package id as prefix or contextDescriptors for parent elements).

Comment: As far as I can tell, I've launched the same apk for each signed with the debug apk.  I'll launch the Heirarachy View and check the ids, but those appear to match what I would expect.   It isn't showing any different dialogs.  I'll try modifying the resource ids in the script to see if that changes anything.  Is there a sample roboscript file anywhere that shows the valid expected format?

Comment: Double checked the files, they are matching up with what the crawler is reporting when I take a look at the accessibilty meta data files.  The ids match what is in the script for the elements.   Screen shots show what I would expect, with no additional dialogs.

Comment: Found the sample scripts in the unpacked directory for the builtin_roboscripts.json

Comment: Thank you for checking! You can use the Roboscript you recorded as a starting point for your experiments (and as one more sample script). As a first step, I would suggest to truncate the recorded Roboscript to a single action and make it use some really simple attributes (e.g., a single contentDescriptor with only 'text' attribute populated). For example, if your app's first screen has a button with some text, your only Roboscript action could be clicking this button using just its text (no resource id, class name, position, etc.).

Comment: I managed to get a partially working script, however, when trying change text in a second MaterialEditTextInput field, it gives an error saying that it it isn't meeting constraints.  Unfortunately the full constraints message is cut off in the logcat.  I can open a seperate question for this if you like.

Comment: This constraint error most probably comes from the underlying Espresso Testing Framework. To debug it further, you can run an equivalent Espresso test that performs the same action in Android Studio and get a more detailed error message. You can record an Espresso test in Android Studio using Espresso Test Recorder (from the main menu, Run -> Record Espresso Test).

Comment: I did figure out the contstraint error, the recorded script was pointing to the text input layout instead of the edit text input.  Once I corrected this, so it pointed to the correct resource Id and removed a bunch of other generated references from it, it started executing all the actions.